# Disabling MariaDb on Debian jessie doesn't work

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian-jessie, init, systemctl

I have MariaDb installed on Debian jessie. I need to remove it from automatic system startup. I tried recommended commands but they did not work:

```
root@debian:/home/gameboy# systemctl disable mysql
Synchronizing state for mysql.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d mysql defaults
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d mysql disable
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
root@debian:/home/gameboy#
```

and

```
root@debian:/home/gameboy# update-rc.d -f mysql disable
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `mysql' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
root@debian:/home/gameboy#
```

After reboot:

```
gameboy@debian:~$ su
Password: 
root@debian:/home/gameboy# ps aux |grep mysql
mysql      722  0.9  2.4 968204 94976 ?        Ssl  00:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root      1686  0.0  0.0  13952  2236 pts/0    S+   00:48   0:00 grep mysql
root@debian:/home/gameboy#
```

and

```
root@debian:/home/gameboy# systemctl status mysql
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-03-27 00:47:56 CEST; 2min 24s ago
  Process: 775 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 773 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 536 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 519 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 496 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 722 (mysqld)
   Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           └─722 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Mar 27 00:47:56 debian mysqld[722]: 2017-03-27  0:47:56 140612694665152 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.35-80.0 started; log...er 1616879
Mar 27 00:47:56 debian mysqld[722]: 2017-03-27  0:47:56 140611906668288 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
Mar 27 00:47:56 debian mysqld[722]: 2017-03-27  0:47:56 140612694665152 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Mar 27 00:47:56 debian mysqld[722]: 2017-03-27  0:47:56 140612694665152 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
Mar 27 00:47:56 debian mysqld[722]: 2017-03-27  0:47:56 140612694665152 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
Mar 27 00:47:56 debian mysqld[722]: 2017-03-27  0:47:56 140612694665152 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
Mar 27 00:47:56 debian mysqld[722]: 2017-03-27  0:47:56 140612694665152 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Mar 27 00:47:56 debian mysqld[722]: Version: '10.1.22-MariaDB-1~jessie'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
Mar 27 00:47:56 debian mysqld[773]: Checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed and upgrade needing tables.
Mar 27 00:47:56 debian systemd[1]: Started MariaDB database server.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
root@debian:/home/gameboy#
```

How to disable automatic start of MariaDb?

**edit:**
This did not help too:

```
root@debian:/home/gameboy# systemctl mask mariadb
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service to /dev/null.
root@debian:/home/gameboy#
```

Comment: Have you tried to mask the service? `systemctl mask mariadb`

Comment: It did not help. I updated the question.

Comment: Did you reboot? Does it dothe same?

Comment: Yes. I did reboot and it still appeared in processes then.

Comment: Try using the _actual_ name, (mariadb) instead of mysql (whatever that is).

Comment: The Galera cluster manager is bringing your service back up. When using Galera, you generally don't manage your database services on each node manually like this. Why are you trying to disable this?

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M I try to disable thisbecause I want to be sure that my docker phpmyadmin uses docker mysql not other mysql and not to stop other mysqls everytime.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this finally worked:

```
systemctl disable mariadb.service
```

To find out correct name see `systemctl list-units` or filter its results ie. `systemctl list-units | grep maria`